# Swift - add text fields and UIImageView with two separate buttons in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I'm making a diary app where I plan on putting two buttons in a view controller, titled "Add Text" and "Add Image". Using these buttons simply allow the user to add a text and an image whenever tapped and drag and resize them as they please, just like how you do it on Instagram's story. Any other plans like using a tableVC or a collectionVC are also ok.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @PPL How to add text fields and UIImageView while in the application. I was wondering if there's a library for it.

Comment: Upvoter explain what did you get from this question.

Comment: @Mani is it possible to add custom uiimage and uitextfield while in app? You'll know what I mean if you have tried Instagram's Story section, or Pages on iOS devices.

Comment: You should not use tableView or collectionView as user is supposed to edit almost everything freely and he might also place one item at another. You should use custom textView and imageView that can listen to tap/drag gestures and update their state accordingly e.g, if textView is tapped, it should show the resizing indicator and it should start listening drag event and update its position accordingly. Something like that.

Comment: @Kamran thank you for the guidance, it actually helped.